# MVC4: Export an .xlsx file to excel through mvc using chrome. It works for .xls but not .xlsx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How can I export an .xlsx file to excel through mvc using chrome. It works for .xls but not .xlsx

```
Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= Estimate1.xlsx");
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

and when i open excel file. it show like this. "Excel cannot open file 'FileName.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid."

so much appreciated your help! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc)

Comment: sorry if i late to say i using MVC4 and when i rendercontrol : grid.RenderControl(htw);  Excel file cant open because file have HTML Tag is in :(

Comment: @LorenzoDematté I wouldn't say that is a duplicate. But it does contain the answer

Answer (score 3):

Try changing content type for `.xlsx`

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the correct MIME type. For DOCX is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/863564) for more details